# ckeditor firefox NS_ERROR_FAILURE: ( should I ignored it ? )

Tags: jquery, firefox, ckeditor

I have an annoying error on firefox with CKeditor. I get the following error in the console

"detailed error: NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsITaskbarTabPreview.invalidate]"

This error is looping until I close the modal

see the screenshot here as I can not attach it to the post :

http://picpaste.com/pics/error-aEHNtvSH.1431614086.png

Here is how I call CKeditor :

```
         $('#open_request').on('show.bs.modal', function ()
            {
                CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
                CKEDITOR.customConfig = 'build-config.js';
                CKEDITOR.replace('description_new_ticket');
            }
        )
```

'description_new_ticket' is a textarea.

This problem appear only on Firefox, however the toolbar and CKeditor are working well .

Should I simply ignore this error ?

Thank you by advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - this kind of error cannot be caused by CKEditor and most likely it also cannot affect CKEditor. AFAIK, these errors are usually some internal exceptions, or errors related to addons. I also found https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1127577 which seems to prove it.

Comment: Hello Reinmar, 
So the question remain, Can I ignore them ? Because I saw that the idea to workaround this error is to use "try, catch", but where I am suppose to put it ?

Comment: If my "most likely" is enough for you then yes - you can ignore them. For me it looks like internal FF's issue. I saw these errors many times and I cannot recall a single case when they caused some problems with a website.